# What's wrong with this mergesort?

Tags: algorithm, coldfusion, mergesort

I'm trying to implement mergesort in Coldfusion, but it is spitting out incorrect results, code:

```
<cffunction name="mergeSort" hint="Sorts arrays of structs">
<cfargument name="arr" type="Array" required="yes">

<cfif Arraylen(arr) LTE 1>
   <cfreturn arr />
</cfif>

<cfset left_ = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset right_ = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset mid_ = Int(Arraylen(arr) / 2)>

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#mid_#">
   <cfset arrayAppend(left_, arr[i])>
</cfloop>

<cfloop index="j" from="#mid_+1#" to="#ArrayLen(arr)#">
   <cfset arrayAppend(right_, arr[j])>
</cfloop>


<cfreturn merge( mergeSort(left_), mergeSort(right_) )>

</cffunction>



<cffunction name="merge" hint="Merges two arrays">
<cfargument name="left_" required="yes" type="Array">
<cfargument name="right_" required="yes" type="Array">

<cfset result = ArrayNew(1)>

<cfloop condition="ArrayLen(left_) GT 0 AND ArrayLen(right_) GT 0">
   <cfif left_[1].attr3 LTE right_[1].attr3>
       <cfset arrayAppend(result, left_[1])>
       <cfset arrayDeleteAt(left_, 1)>
   <cfelse>
       <cfset arrayAppend(result, right_[1])>
       <cfset arrayDeleteAt(right_, 1)>
   </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfif ArrayLen(left_) GT 0>
   <cfloop array="#left_#" index="v">
       <cfset ArrayAppend(result, v)>
   </cfloop>
</cfif>

<cfif ArrayLen(right_) GT 0>
   <cfloop array="#right_#" index="v">
       <cfset ArrayAppend(result, v)>
   </cfloop>
</cfif>

<cfreturn result />

</cffunction>
```

It's sorting an array of structs, on the struct key called "attr3". What happens is that it splits the lists correctly, it seems, but then continues to attach the same list to the resultset. So, for example, if I have left_.attr3 as "Title" and right_.attr3 as "Another", the result ends up being "Title", "Another", "Another", "Another" .. etc.

Comment: btw, pls var scope all your variables!

Comment: Welp. Var scoping the variables fixed the problem. I guess that's what I get for improper coding practices. thanks Henry.

Comment: You should reply so I can choose your answer as correct :)

Comment: @Svante you can easily rewrite the above in coldfusion script. You don't have to use the tag syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [How to sort an array of structs in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653804/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-coldfusion) ?

btw, pls var scope all your variables!

btw, you can join arrays with Java [Join Two Arrays in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081756/join-two-arrays-in-coldfusion)

btw, you can use `mid_ = Arraylen(arr) \ 2` for integer div

Comment: Thanks! Adding some more characters to make this commentable.