# How do I sort this?

Tags: sorting, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Here is a data dump of what I am trying to sort

```
array
1   
     struct
         col           1
         dataid       48
         identifier    1
         row           1
         size_x        4
         size_y        1
2   
     struct
         col           1
         dataid       42
         identifier    2
         row           2
         size_x        2
         size_y        1
3   
     struct
         col           3
         dataid       45
         identifier    3
         row           2
         size_x        2
         size_y        1
```

I want to sort by `row` first, then `col`. Lots of examples how to sort by one data element, but none that talk about secondary elements.

Comment: From where did you get that array in the first place?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13018601/21727) is one solution.

Comment: You could also write your own [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) function and implement your own comparator function that uses both row and col to determine which element is greater.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? (oks update the tagging on the question)

Comment: V10, I go this array from gridster.js (added extra elements).

Comment: mbeckish link he recommended worked flawlessly, had it implemented within minutes.  Thanks man

Comment: None of the answers there are optimal for CF10. See my answer for a CF10 (or Railo) approach.

Comment: Actually [one of the later answers does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235249/104223). I am not sure which one the OP used though.

Comment: Oh, I missed that one... but `arraySort()` doesn't work the way that code suggests. The callback needs to return -1,0,1 not a boolean. However at some stage in CF10's life the behaviour changed. See http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/07/ok-im-very-confused-arraysort-with.html

Comment: *The callback needs to return  -1,0,1* Ah, yes that make sense. Just like a java comparator.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion 10 has built-in customised array sorting using a callback. The docs for [`arraySort()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/arraysort) didn't mention this, but I've just updated them with an example. My example there doesn't show a compound sort like you require, but it's easy enough:

```
<cfscript>
comparator = function(e1, e2){
    e1.row += 0; // need to make sure it's not a string for the Java method call below
    var rowCompare = e1.row.compareTo(e2.row + 0);
    if (rowCompare !=0){
        return rowCompare;
    }
    e1.col += 0;
    return e1.col.compareTo(e2.col + 0);
};

data = [
    {row=3, col=3}, {row=3,col=2}, {row=3, col=1},
    {row=2, col=3}, {row=2,col=2}, {row=2, col=1},
    {row=1, col=3}, {row=1,col=2}, {row=1, col=1}
];

writeDump(var=data);
arraySort(data, comparator);
writeDump(var=data);
</cfscript>
```

This leverages that CF numerics are [`java.lang.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Double%29) objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>

    //ColdFusion 10 only supports this new types of struct declaration
    recordArr = [
            {col: 1,dataid:48,identifier:1,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:1},
            {col: 1,dataid:42,identifier:2,row:2,size_x:2,size_y:1},
            {col: 3,dataid:45,identifier:3,row:2,size_x:2,size_y:1}
    ];

    //ColdFusion 10 only supports this new queryNew() functionality
    queryObj = queryNew("col,dataid,identifier,row,size_x,size_y",
                        "Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer",
                        recordArr);
</cfscript>

<!--- Here it comes our favourite cfquery tag. We can apply order by clause 
as per our wish --->
<cfquery name="ordredResult" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM queryObj ORDER BY row ASC, col ASC
</cfquery>

<!--- Here is the expected result --->
<cfdump var="#ordredResult#">
```