# The ArraySort callback is not sorting my array in the correct order

Tags: arrays, sorting, coldfusion, cfml

Using ColdFusion to sort an multi-dimensional array based on a "Price per sq. ft" field from high to low.

It has been in production and worked in testing, but a case has come up that has yielded strange, unsorted results. I also ran this on the CFDOCS site using [their `ArraySort` code](https://cfdocs.org/arraysort) and got the same, incorrect sort results.

As you can see the results are not even really sorted.

Here's my code:

```
figures = [
   {name='carl',price='117.5'},
   {name='fen',price='116.4'},
   {name='joe',price='86.3'}
];

arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
   return compare(b.price, a.price);
});
writeDump(figures);
```

Results:

```
NAME    joe
PRICE   86.3

NAME    carl
PRICE   117.5

NAME    fen
PRICE   116.4
```

It should be sorted in this order: 117.5, 116.4, 86.3.

I believe it's sorting in a way that makes `86.3` appear greater than the rest because it starts with an 8? I also tried without the quotes and got the wrong results as well.

I ran this same code on cfdocs.org and got the same, wrong results.

Am I doing something incorrectly in my sort parameters or on the callback?

Thank you!

Comment: just to be clear, you want to sort these numbers in alphabetical order?

Comment: Isn't that comparing them as strings?  IIRC the comparison needs to return -1, 0 or 1.  Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of structs in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653804/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-coldfusion)

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Comment: Thanks everybody, I was comparing strings with 'compare' erroneously when I wanted to compare the numerics. Coldfusion 2016 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ArraySort callback function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraysort.html) "compares two elements of the array" at a time, and should return one of the following values:

- `-1` if the first element is *less than* the second
- `0` if the first element is *equal to* the second
- `1` if first element is *greater than* the second

While the [compare()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Compare.html) function does return `1`,`0` or `-1`, it compares the elements as *strings*, which isn't going to produce the expected order for numeric values. As Shawn suggested, adding some debugging code will show the results of each comparison:

```
arraySort(figures, function (a, b){

       local.num = compare(a.price, b.price);
       local.text = local.num == -1 ? " less than " : (local.num == 0 ? " equals " : " greater than");
       writeOutput("<br> "& a.price &" "& local.text &" "& b.price &" => "& local.num );

       return local.num ;
});
```

.. demonstrating that a *string* comparison doesn't produce the same results as a numeric comparison:

- 116.4 less than 117.5  => -1
- 86.3 greater than 116.4 => 1
- 86.3 greater than 117.5 => 1
- 1117.3 less than 117.5 => -1
- 1117.3 less than 116.4 => -1

To sort the "price" values as numbers, use [arithmetic operators](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-expressions-and-number-signs/expressions-developing-guide.html) instead of compare(). For *descending* order (high to low):

```
arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
   return (b.price < a.price) ? -1 : (b.price == a.price ? 0 : 1);
});
```

For *ascending* order (low to high), just swap the comparisons:

```
arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
   return (a.price < b.price) ? -1 : (a.price == b.price ? 0 : 1);
});
```

[Runnable Example](https://trycf.com/gist/2130fbceeffe07cbaae88703ebd6b409/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was comparing string versions of numbers. This example works for me - kudos Ageax!

Answer (score 1):

As @SOS mentioned, it appears the `compare()` function compares numbers as strings even if you wrap them in a `val()`. But where he uses a ternary, you can also use the `sgn()` function instead.

For example...

```
// ascending order
arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
   return sgn(a.price - b.price);
});

// .. or for descending order
arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
   return sgn(b.price - a.price);
});
```

The `sgn()` function will always return a 1 for positive numbers, -1 for negative numbers, and 0 for zero...making it the perfect function (IMHO) for this use case.

Comment: Nice usage of `sgn()`! Added a descending example to demonstrate how easy it is to reverse :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `compare()` function. It can return -1, 0, or 1. Only 0 is considered false. To correct this you need

```
 arraySort(figures, function (a, b){
  return compare(b.price, a.price) == 1 ? 1 : 0;     
 });
 writeDump(figures);
```

Comment: It may have changed, but last I checked it needed to return -1, 0 or 1, like a Comparator.  Also, a string comparison i.e. `compare()` probably isn't what you want for a "price"  Maybe something like this https://trycf.com/gist/2ab55eaeac736f2aeca79ae6fc3ccb04/acf2016?theme=monokai .. Source it this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653804/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-coldfusion

Comment: @Ageax You should post your gist up as an answer.

Comment: @Shawn - I had originally voted to close as a dupe of another thread, which has a similar answer (and many different permutations) though it the -1, 0, 1 answer is way down in the list. If I can't find a clearer dupe, I might do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653804/how-to-sort-an-array-of-structs-in-coldfusion

Comment: @Ageax Since CF has changed _SO_ much in the last couple of versions, I'm always torn on calling CF questions dupes, unless the answer is from a version of CF that is closely related to the version being used. Personally, I'd be happy to purge anything older than CF10, since I think most of those answers continue to contribute to the idea that CF is outdated (not to mention being an unsafe and unsupported versions). But that's a bit of a Meta discussion. I think this is a more detailed question anyway. :-)

Comment: @Ageax And I added a block in you gist to show how `ArraySort()` is stepping through the array, but hit `CTRL-W` instead of `CTRL-S` to save it, and closed the window instead. :-S

Comment: @Shawn - Oh yeah... we've all done that... at the end of a LONG snippet ;-)